# How to auto login into a samba share?

Tags: networking, 22.04, samba

I have two Ubuntu computers.  The first is setup as a NAS, samba installed and all share folders set.  Everything works great.

I also have my Ubuntu work computer.  When I open up my Folder>Other Locations I can see my Ubuntu NAS under "Networks".  When I click on the "Ubuntu NAS" computer none of my shared folders show up. It does not ask for credentials at this time so it's just shows the print$ folder.

If I use "Connect to Server" and enter in smb://myusername:*@MYServerIP the folder mounts and all my folders are visible. I can also use smb://MYServerIP/ShareFolderName which then asks me for credentials and then allows me access to the folder.

I'm new to Ubuntu. Is there a way that I can just click my Ubuntu NAS computer icon and have it auto login my credentials and display my shared folders? I'm used to Windows where the credential manager remembers login info for shares.

BTW. I think part of the problem is that I have the following setting in my smb.conf. Which makes the folders visible only the correct user after they login in.

```
[global]
access based share enum = yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're experiencing is likely due to the `access based share enum = yes` setting in your `smb.conf` file. This setting makes shares visible only after the correct user credentials are provided.

To achieve a more seamless access experience similar to what you're used to in Windows, you can try the following steps:

#### Use GNOME Online Accounts (if you're using GNOME Desktop):

1. Open Settings.
2. Navigate to "Online Accounts".
3. Add a new account and choose "Windows Network Share".
4. Enter the details of your NAS, including your username and password.
5. This should allow automatic connection to the shared folders upon login.

#### Automatically Mount Shares at Login:

- You can add your shares to the `/etc/fstab` file to mount them automatically at login.
- Use the `cifs` filesystem type and include your username and password in the options.
- Example line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//MYServerIP/ShareFolderName /mnt/share cifs username=myusername,password=mypassword,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

- Be aware that storing passwords in plain text in `/etc/fstab` can be a security risk.

#### Create a Script for Mounting Shares:

- If you don't want to use `/etc/fstab` due to security concerns, you can write a script that mounts the shares and run it at login.
- Use `mount.cifs` in your script with the necessary options.
- Add your script to your Startup Applications.

#### Samba Credential File:

- Instead of putting your credentials in `/etc/fstab`, you can use a separate credentials file for samba.
- Create a file like `/etc/samba/credentials`, put your username and password there, and reference it in `/etc/fstab`.

#### Ensure Correct Samba Configuration:

- Double-check your `smb.conf` for any other settings that might be affecting visibility or access.

#### Using a Keyring:

- Store your Samba credentials in a keyring, which GNOME or other desktop environments can use to authenticate automatically.

Comment: Thanks for such a great detailed answer.  I just install Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop. I went to settings>Online Accounts>Add an account.  There is no "Windows Network Share" option. Am I missing something or maybe I need to install another package?

Comment: Oops. It seems that the "Windows Network Share" option might not be directly available in Ubuntu 22.04's default Online Accounts settings. Maybe you can Open a terminal and install the `gnome-control-center` and `gvfs-backends` packages. @fatman

Comment: @fatman if this didn't actually answer your question, then why is this marked as accepted?

Comment: He gave multiple answers. His first option didn’t work for me but the others did.